# URL wont remove /index.php/ How to remove this WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

On my website i got on all my links except the homepage the directory /index.php/... I cant figure out how to get rid of this been searching on the web for a day now and still didnt fix it.
my site is http://www.viscongroup.eu and another link on it is http://www.viscongroup.eu/index.php/news but i want it to be http://www.viscongroup.eu/news how can i get rid of this

Comment: Did you try changing Wordpress permalinks?

Comment: Yes i did and just gave 404 errors

Comment: Rewrite Rule being overwritten by server, Change `Redictions` From Your Cpanel... You will Find `Redirect` Options thare...

Comment: Ill look it up right now

Comment: I don't have Cpanel im using Parallels Panel where can i find Redictions in there?